# Retrieving Windows Phone app reviews & ratings using Zune web API

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing desktop application which aims to help me track my Windows Phone apps reviews and ratings. For that purpose I'm using Zune web API. For viewing ratings and reviews I'm using following feed URL:

> http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/apps/MY_APP_ID/reviews/?store=Zest&chunkSize=100

Where `MY_APP_ID` is a GUID given to my app in marketplace.

The problem is in count of reviews which I'm retrieving. It's always return only the last 100 of them. Regardless of whether I'm removing the `chunkSize=100` or replacing it with `chunkSize=150`. Is there any way to retrieve all reviews or custom fragments/pages of reviews ?

Thanks.

Comment: fyi: http://wp7reviews.tomverhoeff.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked with fiddler, and it seems there are markers in the URL: `beforeMarker` and `afterMarker`, i.e. every response contains also URL to the next and previous page of reviews.